# How do the electromagnetic properties of a dielectric change at relativistic speeds?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

If I have a dielectric structure moving at velocity $v = \beta c_0$ relative to an observer, how do the electromagnetic properties change under relativity.

Can this induce anisotropy or other interesting effects?

[image]

Comment: Related perhaps: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216596/rotating-dielectric-cylinder-in-magnetic-field